# Is there a faster way to integrate this?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

for the following integration:

$\displaystyle\int\limits^{{\pi}}_{0} \dfrac{2}{{\pi}}\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(2nx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$

can I simplify sin(x)cos(2nx) into a simpler form to make the integration easier/faster? i remember there being a simplification for it, but I also remember that it followed certain conditions, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: $\sin a\cos b=\frac12(sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b))$.

Comment: Shouldn't be + instead of - before sin(a - b)?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: @DigiNinGravy : oups ! Yeah, sure :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the identity $$\sin \alpha\cos \beta=\frac12\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\frac12\sin(\alpha-\beta)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\sin (A)+\sin (B)=2\sin(\frac {A+B}{2})\cos(\frac {A-B}{2}) $